# how to give value only to second parameter of a function with default values in python

Tags: python, function, parameters

```
def func(a=2,b=3):
    print(a*b)
```

so this code prints 6 if you call:

```
func()
```

and prints 10 if you call

```
func(5,2)
```

so how do you give the second parameter a value and leave the first one with the default? I already tried

```
func(,4)
```

but doesn't work
this looks good:

```
funk(b=4)
```

but i want to read the values that might or might not be there from an xml file like this:

```
{"a,b":"2,4"}
```

or this:

```
{"a,b":",4"}
```

what do you suggest?

Comment: what's wrong with `func(b=4)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just do `func(b=4)`. This is the beauty of keyword arguments, one of my favourite features of Python :)